# How to programmatically score likelihood that an image is, er, 'personal'?

Tags: image, file, language-agnostic, image-processing

Question: I want to programmatically find image files of a "personal" nature. What characteristics might these files *in general tend* to share (or lack, compared with other image files)?

So far I'm just using:

```
  filesystem.allowExt("jpg");
  filesystem.allowExt("JPG");
  filesystem.allowExt("jpeg");
  filesystem.allowExt("JPEG");
```

`(file.size > 750000 && file.size < 750000000) // bytes`

`(!file.name.compare(0, 4, "DSC_") && !file.name.compare(0, 4, "IMG_")) // no raw camera filenames`

```
float ratio = img.getWidth() / img.getHeight();
if (ratio < 1.8 && ratio > .555555556) // filter out really wide or tall images
```

Other things I think could work:

- Filter out anything that's line-art or scanned text
- Favor images with a high displaysize-to-filesize ratio, i.e. optimized for screen display
- Filter images with large blocks of a single color
- Look for folders in the file path with names like 'pers' 'private' or 'old faxes'

Surely there are more interesting, sophisticated, or funny things these files have in common? (Can you get the number of times a file has been opened programmatically?)

Background: So, I'm doing an art piece about privacy and disclosure. The idea is that it runs on a performer's personal computer and has access to their personal data (yes, I mean what you think I mean*), and displays image files from their user account in various bit-error-mangled formats on screen, mixed in along with other visual effects during the performance of the piece. (Yes, of course they would know about what the software is doing).

They will look (in part) sort of like this, but, you know, more interesting:
[image]

As effective performance involves manipulating things behind the scenes, and I want to maximize the ratio of "personal" files shown to, you know, vacation snapshots, random icons in application-support folders, web-design components, etc. What are some ways I can separate out "personal" files from the rest of these? Obviously there's no way to do this with 100% accuracy, that's not what I'm looking for. Just, on average, what are attributes that these files would/wouldn't have.

*How conservative is SO about discussions like this, anyway? I'm not trying to get political or make people uncomfortable, and I feel like this is a an interesting question that we can discuss here.

Comment: Could you edit your post to focus on the actual question?  The background for this is interesting, but it's not really relevant to the technical problem.

Comment: You can check the JPG's for EXIF data because from those you could derive that the pictures were actually produced by a camera.  Not a decision criterium in itself but it can help narrow down the selection you want to continue analyzing.

Comment: @fvu good idea. Also I've added `if (datecreated == datemodified)` which has a net positive impact for my, um, sandbox environment.

Comment: If I'm following your innuendo right, perhaps you could take an algorithm intended for face recognition and train it with images of other body parts....

Comment: Wait a minute. Why are you excluding filenames from digital cameras? Those seem like they would be the _most_ personal.

Comment: I noticed people often store photos of events, holidays etc in folders that include the year it took place. E.g. 'Holidays 2011' or something like that. So if you find a folder, which name contains the string '20xx', that contains a number of image files you might want to take closer look at those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can train a neural network to classify the images.  Prepare two sets of images: one set of all personal images, and one set of all non-personal images.

Then, use software like [Nueroph](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/image_recognition.html) to train a neural network to learn the difference.  Once trained, you can let the network decide if the image fits into the categories you created.